# Show that $-Z$ is also a standard normal random variable.

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

Show that $-Z$ is also a standard normal random variable; that is, show that $P[-Z < x] = P[Z < x] \,\forall x.$

Comment: Is $Z$ a standard normal random variable and you are asked to show that $-Z$ is a standard normal random variable too? Please don't post incomplete statements of your homework problems here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The standard normal is a symmetric distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the standard normal is a symmetric distribution about $0$ we have $P[Z<0+x]=P[Z>0-x]\forall x\\ \implies P[Z<x]=P[Z>-x]\forall x$

Again note that $$P[-Z<x] =P[Z>-x]\forall x$$Hence it is proved.